# Spring-data настройка теста на тест-базы

Tags: java, hibernate, юнит-тесты, spring-data

Не могу настроить выполнение тестов на тестовой базе. При выполнение всех тестов подключается к рабочей базе (на которой ведутся разработки). Если включить rollback, то тестовые данные после прохождения теста не остаются, но если тест упадёт, то всё что он сохранял останется в рабочей базе. Как настроить, чтобы тест проводился на другой базе?

Конфиг рабочей базы

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"ru.make.alex.web"})
@ComponentScan("ru.make.alex.web.config")
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class HibernateConfig
{
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory()
    {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]
                {"ru.web.model"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment
                .getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource
                .setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource
                .setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory()
    {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("ru.web");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties()
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql",
                environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql",
                environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory)
    {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Конфиг тестовой базы

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"ru.web.test.config"}, excludeFilters =
        {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Configuration.class)})
public class HibernateTestConfig
{
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory()
    {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]
                {"ru.web.model"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mytest?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8");
        dataSource.setUsername("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("user");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory()
    {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("ru.web.test");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties()
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "false");
        properties.put("ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory)
    {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Сам тест

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes =
        {HibernateTestConfig.class, TestConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
@Transactional
public class LooksTest
{
    @Autowired
    private LookFilmService lookFilmService;

    @Test
    public void createTest()
    {
        String название = "Название Фильма";
        LookFilm фильм = new LookFilm();
        фильм.setНазвание(название);
        lookFilmService.сохранитьФильм(фильм);
        List<LookFilm> фильмы = lookFilmService.getФильмы();
        Assert.assertEquals(1, фильмы.size());
        LookFilm lookFilm = фильмы.get(0);
        Assert.assertEquals(название, lookFilm.getНазвание());

        String время = "15:22";
        lookFilmService.отметитьВремяФильма(lookFilm.getId(), время);
        фильмы = lookFilmService.getФильмы();
        Assert.assertEquals(1, фильмы.size());
        lookFilm = фильмы.get(0);
        Assert.assertEquals(время, lookFilm.getВремя());

        lookFilmService.отметитьПросмотрФильм(lookFilm.getId());
        фильмы = lookFilmService.getФильмы();
        Assert.assertEquals(1, фильмы.size());
        lookFilm = фильмы.get(0);
        Assert.assertTrue(lookFilm.isПросмотрен());
    }
}
```

TestConfig

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"ru.web"})
public class TestConfig
{
    @Bean
    public IndicatorsService getIndicatorsService()
    {
        return new IndicatorsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public HomeKubService getHomeKubService()
    {
        return new HomeKubServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

Действия с таблицей все в рамках CRUD. Не пойму почему он тестовый конфиг напрочь игнорирует

Comment: Как вызываются тесты? В идеале интеграционная фигня должна выполняться уже в виде запросов к равзернутому сервису, а не изнутри джарника.

Comment: Запускаю выполнение junit файла LooksTest

Comment: Ну, это не очень правильно (и почему вообще у вас тестовое окружение имеет доступ к продакшен-базе?). Но, насколько помню, вы можете переопределить проперти через `-D`, попробуйте в такой проперти указать другой jdbc url.

Comment: У меня три базы (продакшен, база для разработки и тестовая). Проблема в том, что я не могу настроить тесты на тестовой базе, они производятся на базе для разработке, хотя конфиги описываю. Можно поподробней про "проперти через -D"?

Answer (score 1):

Собственно всё само заработало, единственное, что поменял, так это

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"ru.web.repository"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"ru.web.test.config"}, excludeFilters =
        {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Configuration.class)})
public class HibernateTestConfig
{
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory()
    {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]
                {"ru.web.model"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mytest?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8");
        dataSource.setUsername("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("user");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory()
    {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("ru.web");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties()
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "false");
        properties.put("ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory)
    {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

И в TestConfig добавил

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"ru.make.alex.web.test"})
public class TestConfig
{
    @Bean
    public LookFilmService getLookFilmService()
    {
        return new LookFilmServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public LookSeriesService getLookSeriesService()
    {
        return new LookSeriesServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public IndicatorsService getIndicatorsService()
    {
        return new IndicatorsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public HomeKubService getHomeKubService()
    {
        return new HomeKubServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

Теперь всё тесты выполняются на тестовой базе

Answer (score 0):

> Как настроить, чтобы тест проводился на другой базе?

Если для сборки проекта вы используете Maven, создайте 2 профиля: один для production базы, и другой для тестовой, с различными JDBC URL, соответсвенно. Интеграционные тесты удобно запускать через maven-failsafe-plugin.

Comment: Собираю Maven`ом, попробую такой способ